# Succesfull $.Ajax and $.Post calls always return failure from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

I need a cross domain web api method to return valid jsonp to some javascript from C#. I can't seem to make this magic happen. I've looked around the web and can't find a start to end example that fits my needs and works... Fiddler shows that I'm returning valid json data but when I hit a breakpoint in F12 dev tools or firebug the result is a failure message.

Here is what I've currently got:

C#

```
/// <summary>
/// POST: /Instance/RefreshItem
/// </summary>
/// <param name="instanceId"></param>
/// <returns>Json</returns>
[HttpPost]
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult RefreshItem(int instanceId, Guid customerId)
        {
        try
        {
            var clientConnection = Manager.ValidateInstance(customerId, instanceId);
            clientConnection.RefreshItem();

            var result = new MethodResult()
            {
                Success = true,
                Value = instanceId,
                Message = "Item successfully refreshed."
            };

            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult() { Data = result };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Manager.LogException(_logger, ex, customerId, instanceId);

            var result = new MethodResult()
            {
                Success = false,
                Value = instanceId,
                Message = ex.GetBaseException().Message
            };
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult() { Data = result };
        }
    }
```

JS

```
Example.RefreshItem = function ()
{
    Example.SDK.JQuery.getSettings(
    function (settings, userId, userLocaleId)
    {
        alert("Attempting to refresh item for instance " + settings.ConnectionId + "\r\nThis may take awhile.");

        var url = settings.SystemUrl + "/Api/WebApiServices/ExampleAdmin/RefreshItem?customerId=" + settings.CustomerId + "&instanceId=" + settings.ConnectionId;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: 'RefreshItemCallback',
            success: RefreshItemCallback
        })
    },
    Example.SDK.JQuery.defaultErrorCallback
);
}

function RefreshItemCallback(data)
{
    alert(data.d.Message);
}
```

I've also tried $.Post().Always() with the same results.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: 1. Using JSONP with a POST doesn't make sense. 2. Are you sure you need to be using JSONP? Is this a cross domain request? 3. What's the error you're getting exactly? Is it on the C# side or the JavaScript side?

Comment: This is a cross domain request from the customers MS CRM instance to our azure application. The C# code executes correctly, the current problem is that I don't know the request executed correctly client side. data.d.Message is undefined. data.d is undefined. data is an object that has a few fields that off the top of my head are like status, status text and a few others, one of them just says "fail". If I use .Done() the code is never hit. I have to use .Error() or .Always() when using the $.Post() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fight all week unable to find an answer until you ask the question somewhere... Within 30 minutes of asking I found this: http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/ which was exactly what I needed.

Thanks to all who posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're instantiating a `JsonResult` instead of using the `Json` method.

Presumably the C# method you have is in a controller, so instead of

```
return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult() { Data = result };
```

do:

```
return Json(result);
```

This method probably sets some of the other properties of the JsonResult that, when not set, will not be properly received by the client.

See how Microsoft only shows you how to create a JsonResult via the `Json` method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Note that the same is probably true with methods like `View`, `Content`, and `File`.